# Preencher vetor com TextBox em C#

Tags: c#

Estou tentando preencher as posições de um vetor com entrada de dados vindo
de um TextBox, e fazer a leitura num ListBox mas não estou conseguindo. Tudo parece funcionar, mas só insere o último elemento em todas as posições do vetor.

Trecho do código:

```
int a = 0, i = 0;
private void okClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   //a incrementa à cada click do botão
   a++;
   int[] arr = new int[5];
   for (i = 0; i < (arr.Length); i++)
   {
      arr[i] = Int32.Parse(textBox.Text);
   }
   //limpa o campo do TextBox a cada novo click do botão
   textBox.Clear();
   //Quando a recebe o quinto clique imprime.
   if (a == 5)
   {
      for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
      {
         listBox.Items.Add(arr[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Endrew. Nesse código você está tentando converter o texto do controle `TextBox` em um número inteiro, e você joga o resultado disso nas 5 ocorrências do seu array (sim, o mesmo valor nas 5 ocorrências do array). O que você quer fazer, exatamente?

Comment: Eu digito um número no TextBox e clico
no botão ok.
Enquanto isto a variável inteira "a", é incrementada,
com o click do botão.
O que eu quero é que cada número inserido no
TextBox entre nas posições do array.
Ex: se eu digitar 10, no TextBox, que ele entre
na posição arr [ 0 ] do array,
se eu digitar em seguida 20, que ele entre na
posição arr [ 1 ] do array, e assim sucessivamente
até que complete a operação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá @endrew_lim, observe que em todo click você instancia o objeto `int[] arr = new int[5];`, ao instanciar esse objeto ele inicializa vazio, depois você inclui um valor e quando imprime sempre contém somente o último valor inserido. Você deve instanciar esse array antes do evento click, faça na mesma linha onde você declarou as variáveis `a` e `i`.

Veja como fica: Faça o teste, se funcionar marque como resposta correta ;)

```
int a = 0, i = 0;
int[] arr = new int[5];

    private void ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arr[a] = int.Parse(textBox.Text);
        //limpa o campo do TextBox a cada novo click do botão
        textBox.Clear();
        //Quando a recebe o quinto clique imprime.
        if (a == 4)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(arr[i]);
            }

            ok.Enabled = false;
        }

        a++;
    }
```